# How to get the href attribute using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping, href

I want to retrieve the href attribute of the `<h3>` tags of an html page, I am able to get the innerText, but I don't know how to access the href attribute, there are several `<h3>` tags in the document, but for the time being I just need the first one. I will deal with the rest later...

This is the code I got so far

```
Sub Scrap()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim sDD As String
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://www.oneoiljobsearch.com/senior-reservoir-engineer-jobs/?page=1"
Do
DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Set Doc = IE.document
sDD = Trim(Doc.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).innerText) 
'sDD contains the string "Senior Reservoir Engineer"
End Sub
```

Below is a portion of the HTML document to extract data from:

```
  <div class="front_job_details">

    <h3>
        <a href="/jobs/senior-reservoir-engineer-oslo-norway-7?cmp=js&from=job-search-form-2" target="_blank">

        Senior Reservoir Engineer

        </a>
    </h3>
```

The text I need to retrieve is: "/jobs/senior-reservoir-engineer-oslo-norway-7?cmp=js&from=job-search-form-2"

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
dim hr as string

hr = Doc.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href

debug.print hr
```

The getElementsByTagName collection is zero-based but the .Length (the # of H3's, called Count in other methods) is one-based.

```
dim i as long

for i=0 to Doc.getElementsByTagName("h3").length - 1
    debug.print Doc.getElementsByTagName("h3")(i).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href
next i
```

This gets the first <A> tag from each H3. You could duplicate the method to get multiple A's from each H3.

Comment: Now, how can I loop through all <h3> tags to get all the href in the document? I need to define a collection of some sort, but not sure how, could you please help?

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the following more robust CSS selector method to grab all the hrefs within the class

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetLinks()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer, i As Long, aNodeList As Object
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.oneoiljobsearch.com/senior-reservoir-engineer-jobs/?page=1"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set aNodeList = .document.querySelectorAll(".front_job_details [href]")
        For i = 0 To aNodeList.Length - 1
            Debug.Print aNodeList.item(i)
        Next
        Stop                                     '<=delete me after
        'other stuff
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Below the final code, in case it helps somebody...

```
Sub MultiScrap()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim hr As String
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim i, j, s As Long

Sheets("LNK0").Activate
myHTTP = Cells(1, 2) 'http address root
lval = Cells(2, 2) 'min number to add to root (page=1..)
uval = Cells(3, 2) 'max number to add to root (page=10..)
s = 5

For i = lval To uval 'loop through all pages

    'IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate myHTTP & i
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set Doc = IE.document

    For j = 0 To Doc.getElementsByTagName("h3").Length - 1
        Cells(s, 1) = s - 4 'Correl
        Cells(s, 2) = i 'Page
        Cells(s, 3) = j 'Row in page
        Cells(s, 4) = Doc.getElementsByTagName("h3")(j).getElementsByTagName("a")(0).href 'Http
        hyperAddres = Cells(s, 4).Value
        hyperTxt = Cells(s, 4).Value
        Cells(s, 4).Hyperlinks.Add _
            Anchor:=Range(Cells(s, 4), Cells(s, 4)), _
            Address:=hyperAddres, _
            TextToDisplay:=hyperTxt 'Hyperlink
        s = s + 1
    Next j
    Doc.Close
Next i

MsgBox "Dishes ready Sir!"

End Sub
```