# How to get specific attributes of HTML webpage using excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

This a continuation of a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52248850/how-to-get-the-href-attribute-using-excel-vba/52249946#52249946). In this new post I am trying to capture the contents of the following elements in the HTML code below the following list:

datePosted expected result: "Aug. 18, 2018, 4:19 a.m"

addressCountry expected result: "United States"

addressRegion expected result: "Oklahoma City"

The HTML text is the following:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/JobPosting">  
      <div class="row content">
        <div class="col-sm-3 sidenav well job_detail_lhs">
            <div class="card">
              <div class="card-body">


                        <strong><a href="/?cmp=jd&from=search-more">< Search 32182 More Oil Jobs </a></strong>

                    <meta itemprop="datePosted" content="Aug. 18, 2018, 4:19 a.m." />
                    <meta itemprop="industry" content="Oil & Gas" />
                    <span itemprop="jobLocation" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Place">
                        <span itemprop="address" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/PostalAddress">


                                <h4><strong>Country:</strong></h4>
                                <p itemprop="addressCountry">United States</p>



                                <h4><strong>Location:</strong></h4>
                                <meta itemprop="addressRegion" content="Oklahoma City" />
                                <p itemprop="addressLocality">Oklahoma City</p>

                        </span>
                    </span>
                            <h4><strong>Posted:</strong></h4>
                            <p>22 Days Ago</p>
                    <div>
```

The web page is: [here](https://www.oneoiljobsearch.com/jobs/senior-reservoir-engineer-oklahoma-city-united-states-4/?cmp=js&from=job-search-form-7)

...and the code so far is this:

```
Sub DeepScrap()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument
Dim sDD As String
Dim i, j, s As Long

s = 5

Sheets("LNK0").Activate

Do Until Cells(s, 1) = ""

    'IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate Cells(s, 4)
    Do
    DoEvents
    Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Set Doc = IE.document
    'The first two elements below come from an upper part of the html,
    'I tried different combinations of "getElements" but was not able to 
    'capture them
    htmlTitle = Doc.getElementsByTagName("h1")(0).innerText
    htmlCompany = Doc.getElementsByTagName("h3")(0).getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    htmlCountry = 'need to figure out how to get
    htmlLoc = 'need to figure out how to get
    htmlPost = 'need to figure out how to get

    Cells(s, 5) = htmlTitle
    Cells(s, 6) = htmlCompany

    s = s + 1
    Doc.Close

Loop

End Sub
```

I tried several concatenated combinations of getElementsByTagName but I wasn't able to get the expected results.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: There is no link in your post leading to a webpage. Please include it to get any specific solution.

Comment: Links fixed! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used `xmlhttp` request to make the execution time way faster. ***[.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)*** are very concise and easy to deal with. I've used the same within the below script to locate elements. Check this out:

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const url$ = "https://www.oneoiljobsearch.com/jobs/senior-reservoir-engineer-oklahoma-city-united-states-4/?cmp=js&from=job-search-form-7"
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument

    With Http
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Range("A1") = Html.querySelector("meta[itemprop='datePosted']").getAttribute("content")
    Range("A1").Offset(, 1) = Html.querySelector("p[itemprop='addressCountry']").innerText
    Range("A1").Offset(, 2) = Html.querySelector("meta[itemprop='addressRegion']").getAttribute("content")
End Sub
```

Reference to add to the library:

```
Microsoft XML, v6.0
Microsoft HTML Object Library
```

Comment: You perhaps wanted to get this date `Aug. 18, 2018, 4:19 a.m.` I've fixed that within the script.

Comment: Nice selector use as usual. I have now discovered the API is a company/role within oil and gas and not a useful search term for an application programming interface.

Comment: Excellent, I see that this way is much faster! Can you recommend a tutorial on xmlhttp? I believe I will be using it very often! Thanks for your support!

Comment: QHarr API are the initials of the American Petroleum Institute, they created a measurement of the oil gravity that is usually called API gravity or just API for short. Have a nice week all you!

Comment: [Hit this link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dShR33CdlY8) for the tutorial on xmlhttp request (in it's latter portion) @Pegaso.

Comment: @SIM I got an error '91' at the first line of `Range("A1")`. I have searched a lot of how to get the META data using XMLHHTP but with no luck

Answer (score 2):

Using CSS selectors and IE

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim ie As New InternetExplorer
    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.oneoiljobsearch.com/jobs/senior-reservoir-engineer-oklahoma-city-united-states-4/?cmp=js&from=job-search-form-7"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
           Debug.Print .querySelector("[itemprop=datePosted]").Content
           Debug.Print .querySelector("[itemprop=addressCountry]").innerText
           Debug.Print .querySelector("[itemprop=addressRegion]").Content
        End With

        Stop                                     '<=delete me after
        'other stuff
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Same thing with WinHTTP

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim html As New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        .Open "GET", "https://www.oneoiljobsearch.com/jobs/senior-reservoir-engineer-oklahoma-city-united-states-4/?cmp=js&from=job-search-form-7", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .ResponseText
        With html
            Debug.Print .querySelector("[itemprop=datePosted]").Content
            Debug.Print .querySelector("[itemprop=addressCountry]").innerText
            Debug.Print .querySelector("[itemprop=addressRegion]").Content
        End With             
        Stop                                     '<=delete me after
        'other stuff
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I got an error '91' at the first line of `Debug.Print`. I have searched a lot of how to get the META data using XMLHHTP but with no luck